# How to use json property in a toggle SwiftUI?

Tags: json, swiftui, toggle

I try to program dynamically a toggle to display a shorter list in my SwiftUI project.

The JSON file I use is [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thomjlg/0782e9e8e27c346af3600bff9923f294/raw/9705fb0c6b40eae59578755b86e331bea257972b/films2.json).
My project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/thomjlg/Films-APP). 

I program my toggle like this but when i turn on it, it does not displays a correct list. The goal is to link JSON isShow attribute to the toggle attribute. When toggle is OFF, complete list will be displayed, when toggle is ON, only isShow=FALSE list will be displayed.

```
ForEach(0..<self.userData.movies.filter{ self.showShowOnly == true ?  $0.isShow == self.showShowOnly  : true }.count, id: \.self) { movieIndex in
                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(movie: self.$userData.movies[movieIndex])) {
                                Text(self.userData.movies[movieIndex].nom)
                            }

                        }}
```

The movie struct is

```
struct Movie: Decodable, Encodable, Identifiable {
public var id: Int
public var nom: String
public var idL: String
public var note: Int
public var isShow: Bool

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case id = "id"
       case nom = "nom"
       case idL = "idL"
       case note = "note"
       case isShow = "isShow"
    }
}
```

The json fetcher is :

```
public class MovieFetcher: ObservableObject {
func save(movies: [Movie]) {

    OperationQueue().addOperation {

        do {
            let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(movies)
            let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

            do {
                try encoded.write(to: url[0].appendingPathComponent("movies"))
                print("saved to ", url[0])
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func load(completion: @escaping (([Movie]?) -> () )) {

    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

    do {
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: urls[0].appendingPathComponent("movies")) {

            let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([Movie].self, from: data as Data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(decodedLists)
            }


        } else {
            loadFromJson(completion: completion)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
        completion(nil)
    }
}

func loadFromJson(completion: @escaping (([Movie]?) -> () )) {

    let url = URL(string: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thomjlg/0782e9e8e27c346af3600bff9923f294/raw/9705fb0c6b40eae59578755b86e331bea257972b/films2.json")!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) in
        do {
            if let d = data {
                let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([Movie].self, from: d)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(decodedLists)
                }
            }else {
                print("No Data")
                completion(nil)
            }
        } catch {
            print ("Error")
            completion(nil)
        }

    }.resume()
}
}
```

Do someone know how to correct my code ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter code works. Note there is only 1 movie where "isShow"=true out of 323 movies.

```
  "nom":"Ratatouille",
        "id":217,
        "idL":"R",
        "note":0,
        "isShow":true
```

The problem is the way "movieIndex" is used in the ForEach loop. "movieIndex" refers to the index of the filtered self.userData.movies list. This "movieIndex"
should not be used in self.userData.movies[movieIndex].

To fix this use:

```
                    ForEach(self.userData.movies.filter{ self.showShowOnly ? $0.isShow == !self.showShowOnly : true }) { movie in
                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(movie: movie)) {
                                Text(movie.nom)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Try this and let me know if that works.

Edit: try this class for Movie instead of the struct

```
open class Movie: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable, ObservableObject {

@Published public var id: Int
@Published public var nom: String
@Published public var idL: String
@Published public var note: Int
@Published public var isShow: Bool

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id"
    case nom = "nom"
    case idL = "idL"
    case note = "note"
    case isShow = "isShow"
}

public static func == (lhs: Movie, rhs: Movie) -> Bool {
    lhs.id == rhs.id
}

public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(id)
}

public init(id: Int, nom: String, idL: String, note: Int, isShow: Bool) {
    self.id = id
    self.nom = nom
    self.idL = idL
    self.note = note
    self.isShow = isShow
}

public init() {
    self.id = UUID().hashValue
    self.nom = ""
    self.idL = ""
    self.note = 0
    self.isShow = false
}

public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    self.nom = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .nom)
    self.idL = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .idL)
    self.note = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .note)
    self.isShow = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isShow)
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(nom, forKey: .nom)
    try container.encode(idL, forKey: .idL)
    try container.encode(note, forKey: .note)
    try container.encode(isShow, forKey: .isShow)
}
}
```

Note you will have to change ""@Binding var movie : Movie" to "@ObservedObject var movie: Movie" in ContentView and adjust the "ContentView_Previews".

Comment: Note that Movie is a struct, you cannot change its values, as you do in ContentView, use a class instead or better still class ObservableObject.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I do not see how to adjust the `ContentView_Previews` ... I tried `menu(movie: movie)` but it does not work. I also have to change the `menu()` in SceneDelegate.swift file

Comment: in ContentView_Previews just do: "ContentView(movie: Movie(id: 1, nom: "A", idL: "B", note: 2, isShow: true), note: 3)"

You should not have to change menu() in SceneDelegate.swift

Comment: bone chance avec tes films.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, you want to adjust the filter. If that is correct, try this filter:

```
ForEach(0..<self.userData.movies.filter{ self.showShowOnly ? $0.isShow == !self.showShowOnly : true }.count, id: \.self)
```

This will give you the complete list when self.showShowOnly = false.

And will give you all movies with "isShow=false" when self.showShowOnly = true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right, that's what I want ! I tried your answer but when I tested, i saw that it doesen't work... I think it's because it's link to the JSON file but I have the possibility to change the value of isShow for each film... this is possible with userData... Do you know why your answer does not work ? (you can download my project on GitHub and test, I add you code line in it)